# How to install new module on nginx

Tags: nginx, module, lua, config, echo

I want add a new module to nginx like echo nginx module,But after install module i don't find  ".so" file.when using the ".o" or ".c" module file in "nginx.conf" i have error : "only Et_DYN  or Et_Exec or invalid ELF header."
What is the problem?
Centos 7
Nginx 1.20.1

Comment: Compiling NGINX module on an enterprise OS like CentOS (or any production server, to that extent), is [highly discouraged](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/where-compilation-went-wrong). Either use commercial packages like the ones provided by GetPageSpeed Extras or NGINX Plus, or [build your own RPM packages](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-installable-packages-dynamic-modules/).

Comment: have you found the answer, I do also need to add a module to my nginx ingress controller.